# extract url using preg match

Tags: php, preg-match

I need your help in preg_match. I need data which starting just after ?q= and ends just before &ct

e.g

**i/p -**

http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.sfgate.com/travel/article/Vermont-s-Shelburne-Museum-opens-Pizzagalli-Center-4735584.php&ct=ga&cd=NzIzOTQ3Mjk1NTg1NTg4NjE2OQ&cad=CAE=YAA&usg=AFQjCNHX6CCEmaLgHGzwAy7uVxZOZuL7qw

**o/p -**

http://www.sfgate.com/travel/article/Vermont-s-Shelburne-Museum-opens-Pizzagalli-Center-4735584.php

I dont have any experience of preg_match Please help.It would be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

`parse_url` and `parse_str` are definitely better than regexp in that case.

Comment: can you please give me the code that works with parse_str or parse_url. Thanks!

Comment: No, I can't. Read about this functions in manual. They're pretty easy to use (especially that you can find many examples in manual).